# Optimization related to reduced SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, convex-optimization

The reduced SVD of $B_{m\times n}$ is $USV^T$ and we know the columns of $U$ and $V$ are orthonormal. $e_i$ is the $i$th standard basis vector. I want to know the range of the following optimization problem.

$u_1=max_{i=1,...,m} ||UU^Te_i||^2$

What I have done is: expend $||UU^Te_i||^2=e_i^TUU^TUU^Te_i$, because the columns of $U$ is orthonormal, so $U^TU=I$. Then $||UU^Te_i||^2=e_i^TUU^Te_i=(U^Te_i)^TU^Te_i = ||U^Te_i||^2$. Therefore, the above optimization problem becomes

$u_1=max_{i=1,...,m} ||UU^Te_i||^2=max_{i=1,...,m}||U^Te_i||^2$

Someone claims that $\frac{1}{m}\leq u_1 \leq 1$, but I don't see it because we don't know about the property the rows of $U$. How can we find the range? Please help me:)

Comment: For any orthonormal matrix we have that $U^TU =UU^T = I$, so $u_1=1$. Are you sure you have written down the question correctly?

Comment: Are you aware that $UU^T =I$ ? (Le ft inverse  = right inverse)  So the answer to your problem is 1...

Comment: This may be a reduced SVD?

Comment: @copper.hat Yes it is a reduced SVD. I have modified the problem. Thanks.